# Kendo UI grid - binding to json does not display anything

Tags: jquery, grid, kendo-ui

This is my first time using Kendo UI and I'm trying to set up a simple grid with data fed from a json file.

When the page loads, it doesn't display anything and it does not give me any type of error, am i doing anything wrong?

```
var Data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          transport: {
              read: {
                  url: "http://localhost:88/Animation.svc/GetProspect",
                  dataType: "json"
              }
          },

      });

      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: Data,
          columns: [
    {
        field: "Date",
        title: "Date"
    },
    {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name"

    }],
     height: 200,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: true,
    sortable: {
    mode: "multiple"
    }
      });
```

This is what the json format looks like:
[{"Date":"12-31-2010","Name":"A","LastName":"B"},
 {"Date":"12-31-2011","Name":"B","LastName":"C"}]

Comment: Try it first without the scrollable, pageable, etc. If you don't have the correct .js files for their functionallity, you will get the results you described.

Comment: tried without the scrollable, pageable, etc. same result. I have the following js files referenced:

jquery.min.js
kendo.common.min.css
kendo.default.min.css
kendo.web.js

Am i missing any?

Comment: I'm not sure but here is a link to Kendo UI documentation where they tell you what you need to have. http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies